Raise link targets of section titles when at top of page
The link targets of section titles are usually raised by the current value of \normalbaselineskip. However, when section titles are flowed so that they occur as the first line of a page the link targets are not raised. How to get these section titles to use the default value in order to have consistent behaviour?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Section One}\label{sec:one}

\lipsum[1]

\newpage%% <= Only to illustrate the issue

\section{Section Two}\label{sec:two}

\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}


the link is not raised, the anchor is created in vmode. hyperref tries hard to avoid that the anchor changes spacing by storing and restoring the spaces before the anchor, but at the begin of page this gives different space than inside the document. If you activate the tagging code with \DocumentMetadata{testphase=phase-III} it is different. Then the anchor is hmode.

I suspected it had something to do with vmode from reading and trying "Raising the target" in section 1.2, as well as reading section 2.2 of the implementation in hyperref-linktarget.pdf. In my actual document I'm using \DocumentMetadata{testphase=new-or-1} which was the highest I could successfully use with the KOMA-Script classes. I had tried \section{Section Two}\leavevmode\MakeLinkTarget{}\label{sec:two} to no avail as well.
